# Setting up callback to C function pointer via non-static function in C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

A C header of interest (`some_external_library.h`) declares the following `struct`, containing a function pointer:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    typedef struct {
        void (*function_ptr)(void);
    } fp_test;
    /* ... */
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

When some interesting event happens in `some_external_library.c`, this function pointer gets called.

I would like to set up a pointer to an instance of this `struct` in an instance of a C++ `class` called `Foo`, and then set the value of `function_ptr` to the address of a non-static function with the instance of `Foo`. In other words, I want my C++ code to define what this function pointer does.

For instance, here is a class declaration (`foo.h`):

```
class Foo {
    public:
        fp_test *fp_test_ptr;
        void setup(void);
        void breakdown(void);
        void my_callback(void);
};
```

There are three functions: a `setup` function to initialize values, a `breakdown` function to release any pointers or objects, and a simple `my_callback` function, which takes and returns no arguments.

Here is the class definition (`foo.cpp`):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo some_foo;
    some_foo.setup();
    some_foo.breakdown();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void Foo::setup(void) {
    fp_test_ptr = new fp_test;
    fp_test_ptr->function_ptr = &Foo::my_callback;
}

void Foo::breakdown(void) {
    delete fp_test_ptr;
}

void Foo::my_callback(void) {
    std::fprintf(stderr, "Callback called...\n");
}
```

When I compile this, I get the following error:

```
foo.h:: error: assigning to 'void (*)()' from incompatible type 'void (Foo::*)()'
fp_test_ptr->function_ptr = &Foo::my_callback;
                          ^------------------
```

I tried casting this call, but I get an error message indicating that I cannot cast from type `void (Foo::*)()` to `void (*)()`.

How might I set up a non-static method in C++ to be a function pointer to a C library?

I was able to get a `static` version of `Foo::my_callback()` to compile, but I don't think I can use a static method for my needs, as I will not have access to the states of non-global members in the class instance `some_foo`, only the values of global members.

Is there a way to do this with a non-static function?

Comment: It needs to be static unless you use a proxy. C++ is dumb like that. This happens due to name mangling.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way around this is to have two one functions: one static and one member function and to pass the object instance as a parameter

```
class Foo {
public:
    fp_test *fp_test_ptr;
    void setup();
    void breakdown();
    void my_callback();
    static void _my_callback(void* self);
};

void Foo::_my_callback(void* self)
{
    reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(self)->my_callback();
}
```

Change the C signature of the function pointer to

```
void (*function_ptr)(void*)
```

When you call it, pass the object instance as the parameter.

**Edit:**
To call from C, presumably you need to know which object it refers to so somehow, you need a method of passing the C++ instance to C.

```
Foo* fu1 = new Foo();
Foo* fu2 = new Foo();
/* fu1 and fu2 need to be passed to the C program */
...
/* Setting up */
fp_test pointerTest;
pointerTest.function_ptr = Foo::_my_callback;
...
/* Calling */
pointerTest.function_ptr(fu1);
pointerTest.function_ptr(fu2);
```

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify how I would call the static `Foo::_my_callback(void *)` from the C library side of things? I'm not sure if this will work, as I would have to get `self` from somewhere, and the C library will not have any way of knowing about the object I'm calling this from. All it knows is to call the function pointer when some event happens, which should trigger the function in the C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Every non-static c++ member function has a hidden "this *" parameter. So the function signature will always be different.